# Differentiate betwee sibilant "sssh" voice sounds and instruments like hi-hat?

Tags: fourier-transform, audio, noise, signal-detection

How would I differentiate betwee sibilant "sssh" voice sounds in a music track and a similar sounding instrument sounds like hi-hat or cymbals?

Comment: Are you also expecting the algorithm to separate the "sssh" and "hi-hat" sounds from all the other sounds that could be on a music track.

Answer (score -1):

Find a good pretrained audio classification model, collect some sample data, fine tune the model for your task, use it for inference.

Check [teachable machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/audio), check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVUthvMzkbo) to see it working. It will make the task to look a lot easier than it could be.